# Save multiple UISwitch states different Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, load, save, uiswitch

So I have an app with six views containing all together 36 switches. Is there an easy way to save the states of all when a user flicks them? I heard something about taking them all under a tag or whatever, but have no ideas how this could be done. I want them to get saved and loaded automaticly.

Best regards,
Øyvind Larsen Runestad

Comment: Did you use interface builder?

Comment: You can use the additional properties section in Interface Builder to set a 'keyPath' property for each switch... then use that to automatically set/get properties from your defaults or app controller, etc. Just a direction idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that will store all the state value of switches.

Save that array is user defaults.

At app launch read that file and initialise that array and set the state of switch buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! With much appreciated help from a friend. I gave each one of the switches a unique tag and defined them in my .h as:

```
#define Switchinfour0 100
#define Switchinfour1 101
#define Switchinfour2 102
#define Switchinfour3 103
#define Switchinfour4 104
#define Switchinfour5 105
#define Switchinfour6 106
#define Switchinfour7 107
#define Switchinfour8 108
#define Switchinfour9 109
#define Switchinfour10 110
#define Switchinfour11 111
#define Switchinfour12 112
#define Switchinfour13 113
#define Switchinfour14 114
#define Switchinfour15 115
#define Switchinfour16 116
#define Switchinfour17 117
#define Switchinfour18 118
#define Switchinfour19 119
#define Switchinfour20 120
#define Switchinfour21 121
#define Switchinfour22 122
#define Switchinfour23 123
#define Switchinfour24 124
#define Switchinfour25 125
#define Switchinfour26 126
#define Switchinfour27 127
#define Switchinfour28 128
#define Switchinfour29 129
#define Switchinfour30 130
#define Switchinfour31 131
#define Switchinfour32 132
#define Switchinfour33 133
#define Switchinfour34 134
#define Switchinfour35 135
#define Switchinfour36 136
```

Then, i added this under my (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{

    //Switch save
    NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    for (int i = 100; i < 136; i++)
    {
        UISwitch* sw = (UISwitch*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        [def setBool:sw.on forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Switch%d", i]];
    }
    [def synchronize];
```

Then, right above viewDidLoad i added this:

```
-(void)switchChanged:(id)switchCtl
{
    UISwitch* sw = (UISwitch*)switchCtl;
    NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setBool:sw.on forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Switch%d", sw.tag]];
    [def synchronize];
}
```

And finally, inside my super viewDidLoad i simply added this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    for (int i = 100; i < 162; i++)
    {
            UISwitch* sw = (UISwitch*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
            [sw setOn:[def boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Switch%d", i]]];

        [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
```

I hope this helps any other who struggles with this particular problem.